# MacOS 11,12, and 13 Menubar gone and finder unresponsive

Tags: menu-bar

With more than 5 MacBook pro's I have the problem that sometimes the menubar is gone and finder is unresponsive. only thing working is moving the mouse. I can open up spotlight but cannot type anything.
In Savemode the menu bar is present and the computer works, but after restart menubar is gone again.

Until now the way to solve this problem is to shutdown the computer with the power button. Startup in an other user (for example the Admin user) and switch the user (fast user switching) or logout the admin user and login as the broken user..). A simple restart doesn't solve the problem.

First I thought Sophos antivirus was the problem. But with computers who where clean installed with minimum software programs, the same problem was there..

Any others in here who have the same problem??

Comment: *"sometimes"* - That's not really precise. Are you able to identify a pattern/characteristics when it doesn't work? Maybe a specific app opened? A keyboard shortcut pressed? When you're connected to a specific Wi-Fi/USB cable/Bluetooth device? Or when you have plugged something in your Mac? Also, have you checked there's no anomaly in Activity Monitor? You said that Finder was unresponsive, is it only Finder or are there other apps that are unresponsive? There's many other useful information that could be added to your question.

Comment: The symptoms you describe aren’t common and it appears you have a good sampling of hardware and operating systems to start looking at commonalities amongst them.  Start with a base installation (no 3rd party software whatsoever) on a machine that exhibited the issue prior and see if it continues.  If it doesn’t then you’ve narrowed down the suspects.  Please update with an [edit] as you progress.

Comment: It sounds like a problem in the user domain, if switching to another user fixes it. Check what processes are set to run automatically and in the background in that user account; then check any other non-standard user configuration. Also: the menubar will disappear in Full Screen mode. You're sure that's not happening?

Comment: @Thinkr I described : only thing working is moving the mouse (I forgot to say I can do command space, but cannot fill in anything in the spotlight, so I cannot open up Activity monitor to see what's happening)
Sadly it happens in different surcomstances So until now I cannot find a pattern.
I also described I installed a MacBook with minimum software and with that one same thing happens...

Comment: Topic update: I believe in most cases this happens is when a external screen has been connected.. After that the you can move the mouse, but clicking on something doesn't do anything. You can hit command space for spotlight, but you cannot type anything. A restart doesn't help. Just restart in an other user and when that user is logged in switch users and you're back..